# Fixing incorrectly routed TXB0108

Tags: level-translation

I have a PCB with incorrectly connected TXB0108 (TSSOP20), VCCa 3V3 > VCCb 1V8, that I wanted to use for UART communication between two ICs. I'm looking into various options for fixing it. Here's the TXB0108 pinout:

[image]

One way is to replace it with SN74GTl2003, which allows arbitrary 0.95 V to 5 V translations, and ignore pin 10 OE functionality.[image]

The only question is: do you see any problems with this direct replacement?

Comment: What is incorrect about the TXB0108's connection?

Comment: The pictures you showed are not pin compatible

Comment: @evildemonic VCCa can not be higher then VCCb. In my design VCCa is 3V3 and VCCb is 1V8.

Comment: I don't know what your PCB looks like, but your alternative chip has a different pinout and you will need to do something with the Gref pin.

Comment: @evildemonic sorry I forgot to mention that in my design both a1 and b1 are unused and connected to gnd through a 68k resistor.

Comment: How many boards need to be reworked? You could deadbug the part and wire the GND and OE pins as needed.

Comment: Just one. It's a hobbyist project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GTL requires its GREF/DREF pins to be connected to VCCB with a 200 kΩ resistor, and GND to be a low-impedance connection to ground, and it requires pull-up resistors on all data lines (except for unidirectional down translation).

So to use it in place of the TXB, you would have to make lots of changes to your PCB.

If there aren't too many PCBs, the simplest solution would be to glue the TXB chip to the board on its back, dead-bug style, and add bodge wires.